How can i suppress warnings in Powershell?
I am running the command
az webapp list --query "[].{name:name, resourceGroup:resourceGroup}"  --output json |
    ConvertFrom-Json   

but it gives the warnings ...CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated
How can i suppress these warnings ?
I have tried using
az webapp list --query "[].{name:name, resourceGroup:resourceGroup}"  --output json |
    ConvertFrom-Json --WarningAction SilentlyContinue

but this gives an error
ConvertFrom-Json : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'SilentlyContinue'.

How can i suppress and not show the warnings ?

Given that it's a deprecation warning, is there an alternative command/option that should be passed? I imagine that searching the warning text would reveal a better solution than simply quiescing the warning.

Clarification on the error first, it happens because you're calling a parameter using double hyphens (--) instead of a single one, see about Parameters for more details but, in short:
... | ConvertFrom-Json -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

Would get rid of the error, however it would not get rid of the warning message because it comes from the Azure CLI not from ConvertFrom-Json, to suppress warning messages you should include the --only-show-errors parameter:
az webapp list --query '[].{name:name, resourceGroup:resourceGroup}' --output json --only-show-errors |
    ConvertFrom-Json

Alternatively, you can set environment variables to suppress all warnings in the future:
az config set core.only_show_errors=true

